# Composition: why are "container instance" attributes not updated when "contained instance" are changed?

Tags: python, class, oop, composition, python-descriptors

I would like to better understand the relation between container object attributes and contained object attributes.

I would like to understand the output of this example:

I create a class Car and a class Tire.
Tire also has an attribute age that should "point" to the attribute of the instance of car named bmw. 
So I would think that by changing the attribute of bmw instance the pirelli attribute age should also be updated since it references to the same variable. As visible from the example it is not the case.

How could I do to actually have it updated? 
I am planning of using composition multiple times so in the last class it would be very impractical to use

finalInstance.age = previousInstances.tire.car.age.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

class Tire:
    def __init__(self, car):
        self.car = car
        self.age = self.car.age

bmw = Car(age=1)
print('Car age is ',bmw.age)

pirelli = Tire(car=bmw)
print('Tire age is ',pirelli.age)

bmw.age = 2
print('Car age is now ',bmw.age)
print('Tire age is now ',pirelli.age)
```

I would expect this output:

```
Car age is  1
Tire age is  1
Car age is now  2
Tire age is now  2
```

But what I get is:

```
Car age is  1
Tire age is  1
Car age is now  2
Tire age is now  1
```

Anyone can help me find a way to have self.age = self.car.age of Tire to automatically update?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment operator `=` in Python really changes the object the name assigned to points to.

In other words, in your example, the line `self.age = self.car.age` points to the number (an object) defined in `self.car` when that line is run. When you later run  `bmw.age = 2` that changes the attribute in the car class - it points to a new object. But `bmw.car.age` is not changed.

You have to first understand that well, and that the plain and simple thing to do is just use, even in the `Tire` class, the full path to the attribute `self.car.age`.

Then if you really think you need the attributes to change dynamically, we have to resort to "reactive" programming - an approach in which one change in an state  automatically propagate to other places in the code. Python allows this to be implemented in a number of ways. An example follows.

So, one of the powerful mechanisms Python has to deal with this kind of thing is the "[descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access)" - the language specifies that if an object tied as a class attribute - that is, defined in the `class` body, not just inside the `__init__` or other method - features a `__get__` method (or a couple other special named methods), retrieving or trying to rebind (with `=`) that attribute in an instance of that class will go through this object in  the class. It is called a "descriptor".

Python's `property` decorator uses this mechanism to provide the most used case of creating setters and getters for an attribute. But since you will want the same access and getting rules for a lot of similar attributes, it makes more sense to create an specialised descriptor class - that will "know" the source of an attribute, and always go to its source to get or set its value.

The code bellow, along with the "Car, Tire & Screw"  classes provide an example of this:

```py
class LinkedAttribute:
    def __init__(self, container_path):
        self.container_path = container_path

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def _get_container(self, instance):
        container = instance
        for component in self.container_path.split("."):
            container = getattr(container, component)
        return container

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        container = self._get_container(instance)
        return getattr(container, self.name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        container = self._get_container(instance)
        setattr(container, self.name, value)



class Car:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

class Tire:
    age = LinkedAttribute("car")

    def __init__(self, car):
        self.car = car
        self.age = self.car.age

class Screw:
    age = LinkedAttribute("tire.car")

    def __init__(self, tire):
        self.tire = tire
```

And in the interactive interpreter we have:

```py
In [37]: bmw = Car(2) 
    ...:                                                                                     

In [38]: t1 = Tire(bmw) 
    ...:                                                                                     

In [39]: s1 = Screw(t1)                                                                      

In [40]: t1.age                                                                              
Out[40]: 2

In [41]: bmw.age = 5                                                                         

In [42]: t1.age                                                                              
Out[42]: 5

In [43]: s1.age                                                                              
Out[43]: 5

In [44]: s1.age = 10                                                                         

In [45]: bmw.age                                                                             
Out[45]: 10
```

And, of course, if you don't want to allow any of the parent's attributes to be modified from the contained classes, just leave out (or put a guard flag) on the `__set__` method.

Comment: Thank you @jsbueno for your very detailed answer. I was not aware of the fact that  = in Python changes the object. What the class LinkedAttribute does is exactly what I was asking for. I thought there could be a way of doing it without needing any additional element but I see that probably the most elegant solution is this one. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably more suitable to design a `class Car` that HAS `Tires`, instead of the other way around.

In that case, using property getters and property setters, you can couple the change in the age of the car with the aging of its tires.

something like this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, age, tire):
        self._age = age
        self.tire = tire
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, age):
        delta = age - self.age
        self._age += delta
        self.tire.age += delta

class Tire:
    def __init__(self, age=1):
        self.age = age

pirelli = Tire()
bmw = Car(1, pirelli)
print('Car age is ',bmw.age)


bmw.age = 2
print('Car age is now ',bmw.age)
print('Tire age is now ',pirelli.age)
```

**output:**

```
Car age is  1
Car age is now  2
Tire age is now  2
```

Comment: Could it be done leaving the classes structure as it is in the OP?

Comment: a `Tire` that has a `Car`, that knows not its `Tire`... Yes, it is possible via a `Publisher`/`Subscriber`: a Tire would register with its car to listen the changes in the age of the car, and adjust its own when a `car.age` change is published... That feels a little bit constrained though.

Comment: I am comletely not familiar with `property`ies and `setter`s, but according to your code couldn't it be done by creating a `property` on the Tire's age and implementing it as `return self.car.age`? (referring to the OP code of course)

Comment: Anyway I'm more into motorcycles and they have only 2 so that simplifies the problem... ^-^ haha just kidding. Anyway I agree but again, I am not familiar with that technique and was asking out of curiosity to learn. Also in the OP code Tires don't even have age... Thanks alot!

Comment: the major problem with this code is that `Car` has to know and deal with attributes within each of the classes that would use any of its attributes in this way. Also, attributes in the linked classes are just as static - if they are changed there, that chaneg won't reflect here.

Comment: The downvote because it really does not explain what is wrong with the example in the "OP' - just taxes it as unsuitable, when it really is not - in a big code base, it makes sense to have cars "knowing' of their tires, but this approach requires one to create all of the car components first before the car can even be referred to as an item. Having components register themselves in the parent, is  much more "suitable" (and unneeded in the minimal and complete example in the question)

Comment: okay, thank you @jsbueno for trying to teach me; the OP's example was contrived to start with: a `Tire` that has a `Car` doesn't make sense in most situations; it is self explanatory, once the onus is put on it. I don't address this either, but what happens to `LinkedAttribute` when you put new tires on an old car? This is probably a problem that is oversimplified so it soon stops making sense. The perspective of a large legacy code base is fine... I tend to believe that techniques like descriptors were specially developed for those cases where tires have cars, and that cannot be changed!

Comment: The "when a car gets new tires" scenarios is included in the answer - if one does not want an attribute to be updated in the parent, it should be changed in `__set__` on the descriptor. But yes - in a big and full system, a "Car" would be described as having 4 tire slots - probably being instantiated automatically - and one have to define a way in the framework of how to comunicate the relations of all attributes across those. "LinkedAttribute" is also a minimal example - but one that  as "property" can be put to many uses.

Comment: As more "in use on the real World" on how one-to-many relationships work without needing to be declared in the parent, you can check how these works in the popular ORM's: both SQLAlchemy and Django's.

Comment: Thank you all, especially @ReblochonMasque and jsbueno (already thanked above) for your comments. I am aware that the example I showed is maybe not the most representative of a real world problem and reversing the dependency would be better. Anyway the central concept that I wanted to question about was the updating of the attributes of the container/contained objects and you helped me in understanding the underlying logic about it.